# python tuple single element

Tags: python, tuples

I understand from Python tutorial that to create a tuple containing a single value you have to include a comma, even though there is only one value:
`tup1 = (50,)`
What is the significance for putting comma at the end of the constructor?

Comment: The comma defines the tuple, not the parenthesis. `tup1 = 50,` is a tuple.

Comment: Because `(50)` is just a grouped expression, not a tuple. The comma defines tuples, not parentheses, although in many contexts you need to use parentheses anyway to disambiguate the comma.